# Display Top Portion of UIImageview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I'm trying to display a top portion of an UIImage.

I know I can use the following code and display the middle portion. I'm just trying to figure out how to do the same for the top portion:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

The UIImage I get from the server is not necessarily the same size, so I cannot use UIViewContentModeTopLeft. I want a way to scale the image and show the top portion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to display an arbitrary rectangle of your image, so the easiest way to go will to be to put your imageView inside a regular view.  You can set the frame of the image view to display the bit you want and set the enclosing view to do the clipping.

e.g. you have a 1000 x 1000 px image and you want to display the rectangle 200,200 to 400,400

```
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImage"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake( -200, -200, 1000, 1000);
UIView* enclosingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 200, 200);
enclosingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[enclosingView addSubview: imageView];
```

Content mode doesn't matter much in this case, since you're setting the dimension of the image view to match the image.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` on your original image to create a new image with just the top portion.

Something like:

```
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( oldImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(0,0,50,50) );
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];
CGImageRelease( newImageRef );
```

then display newImage rather than oldImage.